# Acceder a atributo de un elemento en InternetExplorer con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una serie de botones que cuentan con el evento onclick, como el siguiente:

```html
<button class="tablinks" containerid="primary" onclick="Page.loadTabs(event, 'tab-2'); return false;">Seguridad</button>
```

Al hacer click sobre el botón, se envía la información del evento y otro texto que necesito.

Me gustaría saber como acceder a la propiedad "containerid" del botón. Usando la información del evento que recibe.

Para la mayoría de los navegadores funciona de la siguiente forma:

```js
loadTabs: function (evt, tabId) {
              
  var container = evt.toElement.attributes.containerid.value
  
}
```

Pero necesito que también funcione en Internet Explorer, y no logro acceder al valor.

¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo acceder al valor desde internet explorer?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la forma que encontré fue la siguiente:

```
evt.srcElement.attributes.containerid.value
```

De esta forma funciona en IE.

Lo dejo por si a alguien le sirve en el futuro.